# Get Keycloak access_token using client credentials using axios throws 400 error in NextJS app

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js, keycloak

I am trying to get the `access_token` from keycloak using axios using client credentials. However, I am getting a 400 error when I use axios post request to get the access_token.

I havet tested my client credentials using postman and it does return the access__token however, when using in a NextJS app I get a 400 error:

currently inside my `_app.tsx` file I have the following method:

```
const getToken = () => {
  let token: string = undefined;
  const realm = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM;
  const keycloakClientSecret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_BEARER_CLIENT_SECRET;
  const kcTokenEndpoint = `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: kcTokenEndpoint,
    data: {
      client_id: 'keycloak-token-bearer', // create client in keycloak with same name
      client_secret: keycloakClientSecret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  })
    .then(response => {
      token = (response as any)?.access_token;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      token = undefined;
    });

  return token;
};
```

Which I see returns a `400 (Bad Request) error`
When I check the response I see the following:

```
error   "invalid_request"
error_description   "Missing form parameter: grant_type"
```

Answer (score 3):

`axios.post` is an async operation. Currently you always return `undefined` from your function because you are not waiting for `axios` request to resolve.

If you have async function then you can only return a promise from it.

So you either need to do that:

```
  // Add return here
  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: kcTokenEndpoint,
    data: {
      client_id: 'keycloak-token-bearer', // create client in keycloak with same name
      client_secret: keycloakClientSecret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  })
    .then(response => {
      // Return token here
      return (response as any)?.access_token;
    })
```

Or make `getToken` function `async` and `await` axios request:

```
const getToken = async () => {
  const realm = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM;
  const keycloakClientSecret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_BEARER_CLIENT_SECRET;
  const kcTokenEndpoint = `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

  cosnt { response } = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: kcTokenEndpoint,
    data: {
      client_id: 'keycloak-token-bearer', // create client in keycloak with same name
      client_secret: keycloakClientSecret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  })

  return response.access_token;
};
```

Obviously now you need to `await` `getToken` function or use `then(...)` too

Comment: okay thanks - but then how can I use `headers: getToken()` after this?  this will return a Promise<any> in Typescript

Comment: Same way, `await` for it

Answer (score 1):

use URLSearchParams for encode request.

```js
const getToken = async () => {

  const params: {
      client_id: 'keycloak-token-bearer', // create client in keycloak with same name
      client_secret: keycloakClientSecret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    },

  const dataParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  const realm = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM;
  const keycloakClientSecret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_BEARER_CLIENT_SECRET;
  const kcTokenEndpoint = `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

  const { response } = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: kcTokenEndpoint,
    data: dataParams,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  })

  return response.access_token;
};
```